# Porting GIT Repositories (with a lot of branches) into Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

we want to move our current GIT repositories (about 9-10) with about 20-50 branches each to gerrit. Do we really have to push each single branch (worst-case: 500 branches!) manually into gerrit or is there a better solution? The gerrit daemon will run on the current git server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Just move the repositories using filesystem commands to the correct location on your server.  The Gerrit daemon will pick them up without any problems.
2. Push them to the server using git bypassing review.  `git push $SERVER$ refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` should work just fine.  You'll need to do this once per repository and it will push all the branches in that repository.  You'll need permissions on Gerrit to create branches and bypass review.

Comment: It is important, which Gerrit version you use. With Gerrit 2.2.1, parts of the configuration were moved from the database to the repositories itself. Thus, and due to a bug, you need an empty branch refs/meta/config in your repositories, otherwise you get an exception in the web interface, if you visit the project configuration pages.

Answer (score 0):

Branches are very light in git. It shouldn't be an issue.